# append text name to each input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to add input dynamically. However each input I add is blank without a name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var moreUploadTag = '';
    $('#attachMore').click(function() {
        moreUploadTag += '<input type="text"/>';
     jQuery(moreUploadTag).detach().appendTo("#boxed");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div id="boxed">
  <input type="text" name="" />
 </div>
  <p id="attachMore">attachMore</p>
```

The purpose I left it blank without a name is I want to crate the name dynamically:

```js
$('#addName').click(function(){
 //$('input').attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + "test");
 var named = $('input').val();  
 $('input').attr("name", $('input').attr("name") + named); 
});

$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#attachMore').click(function() {
        var moreUploadTag = '';
        moreUploadTag += '<input type="text"/>';
     jQuery(moreUploadTag).detach().appendTo("#boxed");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxed">
  <input type="text" name="" />
 </div>
  <p id="attachMore">attachMore</p>

  <p id="addName">addName</p>
```

However it adds name to all input.

My question is how to add name input each of the inputs?

Thanks in advance for the help. Cheers.

Comment: How would you like to assign the name? What is the expected result when clicking `addId` (also note that is really extrange to call it "addId" when it changes the `name` and not the `id` of the element.

Comment: smart question. I would like to assign the name based on the value typed in the input. I edit the code. thanks in advance.

Comment: I still don't understand the question: Lets say you add a new input, so now you have 2 inputs. In the first one you write "A" and in the second one "B". Then you click `addName`... what would you expect? What name should have each input? Right now both will have `name="A"`

Comment: ^that's my question. Right now when I click `addname`, it will add the same name for all inputs. What I want is to add name to each input based on their each value.

Comment: Have you noticed that your `#attachMore` button adds first one input, then two, three, and so on? You must assign the `moreUploadTag` outside the `#attachMore` click listener and then append it to the `#boxed` div to add only one input for each click

Comment: Omg, I just noticed that. Thank you for the info. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$('#addName').click(function(){
 $('input').each(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        input.attr("name", input.val()); 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#attachMore').click(function() {
        var moreUploadTag = '';
        moreUploadTag += '<input type="text"/>';
     jQuery(moreUploadTag).detach().appendTo("#boxed");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxed">
  <input type="text" name="" />
 </div>
  <p id="attachMore">attachMore</p>

  <p id="addName">addName</p>
```

Comment: `var one_word = 'perfect'.` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you need to tell jquery what name goes with what input.

```js
var inputHtml = '<div class="inputGroup"><input type="text" /><button class="addName">add name</button></div>';
var yourname = 'allen';

$('.body').on('click', '.addInput', function() {
  $('.target').prepend(inputHtml);
});

$('.body').on('click', '.addName', function() {  
  if($(this).siblings('input').length) {
     $(this).siblings('input').attr('name', yourname);
     // debug 
     alert($(this).parent().children('input').attr('name'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
<div class="target"></div>
<button class="addInput">add input</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it still gives the same name for all input. What I want is it adds name to each inputs based on each value typed in the input.

Comment: The matter is, yes, to tell jquery what name goes with what input. Can you make it for me, please?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put the add button outside of the group. you need to replace yourname with $.value();